# Replacing newline character in UNIX

Tags: java, windows, unix, newline

I'm making a code to replace a newline character from a string. On Windows, when I use

```
String.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "\\n");
```

this works fine, but it fails in UNIX.

What should i use in UNIX ?

Comment: @Tichodroma's edits broke the code. Now it says `\\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is correct for Unix. Windows uses `\r\n` and Mac uses `\r` IIRC.

The problem may lie in the fact that Java, being a multiplatform language, automatically replaces `\n` with the system's separator. I don't know Java but I assume this is the case.

Edit: If the code you posted is what you're using, I think I see the problem. `String` is a class. It is also immutable in Java. It should instead be this:

```
String myStr = "abc\ndef";
myStr = myStr.replaceAll(/* params */);
```

Comment: In my case, from somewhere i receive a text which i have to set it in a string. and when there is a ENTER key pressed in string, it comes in 2 lines, so wanted to replace it with \n so that when new string is executed it displays correctly.

When i use in windows, the java code does what it should do, but not in unix.

so should i use String.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");  ??

Answer (score 0):

The text being received probably contained windows line separators, so replacing just the `\n` character had no effect.

If you don't know the origin of the text (or the text contains a mixture of line separators), the following approach can help. First convert windows and mac line separators into unix separators, then convert the unix separators to the system separator.

```
final String DOS = "\r\n", NIX = "\n", MAC = "\r";
String converted = original.replace(DOS, NIX)
                           .replace(MAC, NIX)
                           .replace(NIX, System.lineSeparator());
```